# Why am I getting dictionary key arror

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a JSON file which has nested dictionaries and when fetched the value of top tree the data looks like below. I need to iterate to below data and fetch information of each element like

```
{
   "access-policy":[
      {
         "name":"Allow_Redundant_Device",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-Internet1-Failover-Zone",
                     "Intf-Internet1-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-Internet1-Failover-Zone",
                     "Intf-Internet1-Zone"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"allow",
            "lef":{
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"Allow_From_Hostbound",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "HOST-GLOBAL-Zone"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-Global-Zone",
                     "ptvi"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"allow"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"Network_VPN_WEB_TEST",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GLOBAL-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-list":[
                     "VPN12",
                     "1VPN"
                  ],
                  "address-group-list":[
                     "VPN1"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "L-ST-GLOBAL-Internet1",
                     "L-ST-GLOBAL-Internet2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "services":{
               "predefined-services-list":[
                  "http",
                  "https"
               ]
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "security-profile":{
               "ips":{
                  "predefined-ips-profile":"Versa Recommended Profile",
                  "predefined-ips-profile-override":"Predefined-alert-IDS"
               },
               "url-filtering":{
                  "user-defined":"EMEA_NETWORK_VPN_WEB"
               }
            },
            "action":"allow",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "tcp-session-keepalive":"disabled",
            "lef":{
               "profile":"Default-Logging-Profile",
               "event":"both",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"GLOBAL-TO-SDWAN",
         "number":1,
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GLOBAL-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "ptvi"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"allow",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"Allow_From_SDWAN",
         "number":2,
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "ptvi"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"allow",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"DENY_MGMT_SERVERS",
         "description":"CHGxxxx",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GLOBAL-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-group-list":[
                     "AD_MGMT_SERVERS"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "L-ST-GLOBAL-Internet1",
                     "L-ST-GLOBAL-Internet2"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"deny",
            "tcp-session-keepalive":"disabled",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"DMZ-APPS-FILTERING",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GUEST-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-list":[
                     "1NETS",
                     "2NETS"
                  ],
                  "address-group-list":[
                     "1GUEST",
                     "2GROUP"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet1",
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "application":{
               "filter-list":[
                  "Malware_With_High_Risk"
               ]
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"deny",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "tcp-session-keepalive":"disabled",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"URL-FILTERING",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GUEST-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-list":[
                     "2-NETS",
                     "1-NETS"
                  ],
                  "address-group-list":[
                     "1GROUP",
                     "2GROUP"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet1",
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "url-category":{
               "predefined":[
                  "adult_and_pornography",
                  "confirmed_spam_sources",
                  "dead_sites",
                  "gross",
                  "hacking",
                  "malware_sites",
                  "nudity",
                  "open_http_proxies",
                  "peer_to_peer",
                  "phishing_and_other_frauds",
                  "proxy_avoid_and_anonymizers",
                  "spam_urls",
                  "spyware_and_adware"
               ]
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"deny",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "tcp-session-keepalive":"disabled",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"PUBLIC-DNS",
         "match":{
            "source":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "Intf-GUEST-Zone"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-list":[
                     "1-NETS",
                     "2-NETS"
                  ],
                  "address-group-list":[
                     "2-GUEST",
                     "3-GROUP"
                  ]
               },
               "user":{
                  "local-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "external-database":{
                     "status":"disabled"
                  },
                  "user-type":"any"
               }
            },
            "destination":{
               "zone":{
                  "zone-list":[
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet1",
                     "L-ST-GUEST-Internet2"
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "address-list":[
                     "dns-google",
                     "dns-google1"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "services":{
               "services-list":[
                  "dns"
               ]
            }
         },
         "set":{
            "action":"allow",
            "synced-flow":"allow",
            "tcp-session-keepalive":"disabled",
            "lef":{
               "event":"never",
               "options":{
                  "send-pcap-data":{
                     "enable":false
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Out of above to fetch the information of the key source and destination I extracted out below key value of key=source.

When I am trying to fetch data, for example

```
data_src = {'zone': 
               {'zone-list': ['Intf-GLOBAL-Zone']
               }, 
                'address': 
                   {'address-list': ['Netowkr1', 'Netowkr1'], 'address-group-list': ['SOMEDATA']
                   }, 
                    'user': 
                       {'local-database': {'status': 'disabled'}, 
                        'external-database': {'status': 'disabled'}, 
                        'user-type': 'any'
                       }
                    }
```

data_src['zone']['zone-list']  --> this gives me list of zone properly

data_src['address']['address-list'] this doesn't give me any key value and throws

```
address_list = policy_source['address']['address-list']
```

KeyError: 'address'

I am stuck here from almost one day. Can you guide me how I can get this corrected.

I have a huge file where I need to extract data of below fields to an excel for each of the line data inside json file.

For each iteration of line I need to extract below data

Out of source : key

'name'
'description'
zone-list'
address:

Out of source : key
'name'
'description'
zone-list'
address

Then rest of the data

'services'
'set'
'action'
'lef'

Let me know if anything else is required.

for now before defining a function patter for this one i am trying to read each dictionary to formulate the code

```
import json
import csv

with open("rule.json") as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)
    read_index = read_content['access-policy']

    for policy_data in read_index:

        policy_name = policy_data['name']
        policy_elements = policy_data['match']

        policy_source = policy_data['match']['source']

        print(policy_source)

        print(policy_source['zone']['zone-list'])  #This works fine

        #below doesnt work as this should be the next key value
        print(policy_source['address']['address-list'])
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid format. Can you fix and reformat so it's easier to read.

Comment: I updated your json to show you that your JSON is not a valid format. There are some missing pieces. Can you fix it first before you ask for help.

Comment: Hello Joe my bad yes i missed this... done please check if this one works

Comment: 'policy_source' isnt defined anywhere in your question. `data_src['address']['address-list']` works just fine. I suspect that your problem comes from whatever you did to derive `policy_source`.

Comment: just added the code as well to the request

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to have 'address-list'. You have to parse multiple times in the nested json. `s` in `loads` stand for string, so parse that much time until you get that. You can use this:

```
x = json.dumps(data_src)
t = json.dumps(json.loads(x).get("address","{}"))
json.loads(t).get("address-list")
```

[image]

Comment: actually i need to extract all the values that i mentioned in the main body

Comment: with this you can write a function with above logic and parse the nested json through ```loads``` till that point you need the corresponding data and then append that variable in csv file which you want